# Understanding the window.event property and its usage

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

I don't understand the motivation behind window.event or window.event.srcElement. In what context should one use this? What exactly does it represent in the DOM?

Answer (score 20):

Here what [w3school says](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) about `event` object:

> Events are actions that can be detected by JavaScript, and the event
>   object gives information about the event that has occurred.
>
> Sometimes we want to execute a JavaScript when an event occurs, such
>   as when a user clicks a button.

You can handle events using:

```
node.onclick = function(e) {
  // here you can handle event. e is an object.
  // It has some usefull properties like target. e.target refers to node
}
```

However Internet Explorer doesn't pass event to handler. Instead you can use window.event object which is being updated immediately after the event was fired. So the crossbrowser way to handle events:

```
node.onclick = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  // also there is no e.target property in IE.
  // instead IE uses window.event.srcElement
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  // Now target refers to node. And you can, for example, modify node:
  target.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
}
```

Comment: Apart from that you draw from w3schools, this is the most useful answer here. +1.

Comment: “_`e.target` refers to `node`_”: This is wrong. `this` refers to `node` whereas `e.target` can refer to any child element of `node` depending on which one has been clicked and whether the event bubbles or not, etc.

Comment: Is that true for all versions of IE? I realize this is an old question, just curious... couldn't find anything on it

Comment: Do you still have to use window.event? Till what version?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this difference has been changed in newer browser versions but basically, "In the Microsoft event accessing model there is a special property window.event that contains the last event that took place." (from reference)

So, to write an event handler compatible across browsers you'd need to do something like this:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if(!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    var ele = e.target || e.srcElement;
    // get the clicked element
    // srcElement for IE, target for others
}
element.onclick = doSomething;
```

Reference:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html

Answer (score -1):

```
function IndentifyMe(){
 alert("You clicked on " + window.event.srcElement.tagName);
}

<body onclick = "IndentifyMe()">
```

Try this code, with lots of element in body tag, and try clicking different element

Answer (score -1):

**Events** are the lifeblood of user interaction. Without events, you
couldn't interact with the page.

Event handlers are used to invoke some JavaScript when a certain action happens. If you want some
behavior to be triggered when the user moves their cursor over an element, you use the onmouseover
event handler.

*"DOM Scripting: Web Design with JavaScript and the Document Object Model: Second Edition"*