# Understanding Event Handlers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, handler

I am going over event handlers in JavaScript right now. I am not understanding this
example in our textbook. For example, I understand mousestatus(e) is a function with 'e' as the parameter
of this function. What I do not understand is the following:

```
   if (!e) e = window.event;
    btn = e.button;
```

and lastly this entire block

```
  }
    message=e.type + " : " + whichone + "<br>";
    document.getElementById('testarea').innerHTML += message;
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    obj=document.getElementById('testlink');
```

below is the full script

```
    function mousestatus(e) {
      if (!e) e = window.event;
      btn = e.button;
      switch(btn) {
        case 0:
          whichone = "Left";
          break;
        case 1:
          whichone = "Middle";
          break;
        case 2:
          whichone = "Right";
          break;
        default:
          whichone = "UNKNOWN";
      }
      message=e.type + " : " + whichone + "<br>";
      document.getElementById('testarea').innerHTML += message;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    obj=document.getElementById('testlink');
    
    obj.addEventListener("click", mousestatus);
    obj.addEventListener("mousedown", mousestatus);
    obj.addEventListener("mouseup", mousestatus);
    obj.addEventListener("dblclick", mousestatus);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to something a little clearer. Use proper markup, and fix up the description a bit because right now the code you're showing doesn't seem related to the text you've written leading up to it.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+what+is+window.event) of [Understanding the window.event property and its usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6926963/4642212); see the documentation on [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). `e.button` is [`MouseEvent.prototype.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button); the code itself says `Left`, `Middle`, and `Right`, referring to the left, middle, and right mouse buttons.

Comment: `if (!e) e = window.event` you can thank microsoft internet exploder for this abomination - which apparently chrome and firefox have now taken on board (just so sites written to be run in internet exploder only - thank you microsoft - have a better chance of running in these browsers I guess)

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh, Et tu Firefox? I thought it was the last bastion of rationality in this regard.

Comment: @VLAZ - yes, appeared in 63, then in version 66 it was finally enabled by default

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I made an edit to the question. Does that clear things up?