# Is `event` an implicit variable?

Tags: javascript, eslint, stimulusjs

Given this code:

```js
export default class {
  bar () {
    event.foo()
    arguments.foo()
    foo.foo()
  }
}
```

When you run the [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) eslint rule, you get this back:

```
test_controller.js
  5:5  error  'foo' is not defined  no-undef
```

`foo` isn't defined, so that error makes sense.

`arguments` is implicit (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) so the lack of error makes sense.

But where is `event` defined? I'm not aware of it being an implicit variable the way `arguments` is. I thought this was a bug in `no-undef`, but I extracted this example from some [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/) code that works fine without the `event` parameter. So I want to understand if there's some general JS behavior I'm not aware of here.

For the record (though I'm not sure it matters here), Stimulus calls the function [here](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/blob/848e0c7d20cec7c6b2d29b10ad3864cae50e645b/packages/%40stimulus/core/src/binding.ts#L51) and does pass an `event` parameter. But only the name `event` works "magically" and that's what's really doing my head in. Note that my simplified example doesn't reference Stimulus at all.

Comment: It's not implicit, it's global: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event (or rather: *was*).

Comment: [Why is 'event' variable available even when not passed as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33167092) | [Understanding the window.event property and its usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6926963) | [What is window.event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31544108) | [Javascript events: window.event vs argument reference (function)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29423624)